# Shiny - button works only once

Tags: r, shiny

I've this shine app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionBttn(inputId = "start",label = "start",color = "success",style = "material-flat")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input[["frst"]], {
    print("frst")
    ask_confirmation(
      "frst1",
      title = " ",
      type = "question",
      btn_labels = c("OK"),
      html = TRUE,
      text =   "frst"
      
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input[["scnd"]], {
    print("scnd")
    ask_confirmation(
      "scnd1",
      title = " ",
      type = "question",
      btn_labels = c("OK"),
      html = TRUE,
      text =   "scnd"
      
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input[["start"]], {
    
    ask_confirmation(
      "fff",
      title = " ",
      type = "question",
      btn_labels = c("OK"),
      html = TRUE,
      text =   div(
      actionBttn(inputId = "frst",label = "frst",color = "success",style = "material-flat"),
      actionBttn(inputId = "scnd",label = "scnd",color = "success",style = "material-flat")
      )
  
      )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I click on start button I get a pop-up window (shinyWidgets),
which contains 2 button (actionBttn) and in addition the OK button.
when I click on the "ftst"/"scnd" button I get another pop-up window.
But it works only once time. In the first time it's works well.
But if I try to do it in the second time, nothing happened when I click on the button.
How can I fix it? witout using the "ok"/"cancel" button of the shinyWidgets.
I want to use in the actionBttn.

Comment: I've never created a widget within a server except for the use of renderUI, if I had to guess its because you created your shiny widgets within the server rather than the UI

Comment: If you repeat an action button (or any input element) in an app, you'll see the second instance doesn't work. Input elements must be unique. Test by duplicating a button, you'll see the second instance doesn't work. When the start confirmation alert is launched a subsequent time, it's duplicating buttons, it's not calling a UI that exists uniquely, but rather creating them again. These duplicates don't work. I think the widget is not meant to work this way. Native modal dialogs in Shiny do allow you nest input elements.